No connection even if it connected to hotspot
I have a problem with internet connection on my Ipad. I create a hotspot on my Android phone and connect to it on my iPad, but after a while, the connection stops working, and the pages on the iPad appear as if I were not connected. However, the connection on the phone works for me, and even on the iPad, I have the hotspot icon, and it looks like I'm connected. If I turn off and on the hotspot on the phone, it works again for a few minutes, and then the connection on the iPad stops working again. I have a problem with connecting to my tablet. I create a hotspot on my Android phone and connect to it on my iPad, but after a while, the connection stops working, and the pages on the iPad appear as if I were not connected. However, the connection on the phone works for me, and even on the iPad, I have the hotspot icon, and it looks like I'm connected. If I turn off and on the hotspot on the phone, it works again for a few minutes, and then the connection on the iPad stops working again. I've tried various updates, but I don't know what to do. It's annoying. Thank you for the advice. It's annoying. Thank you for the advice.
I've tried various updates, but I don't know what to do. I also tried to turn off power saving mode on mobile but also without success.
